# Retired and sick parents to Germany

Tags: germany

I am a Portuguese citizen and I've just moved to Germany. My mother is 74, lives in Portugal, is very sick at the moment, and is in some way dependent.

- Are there possibilities or conditions for me to take to her to live with me in Germany?
- What do I need to do to make the process move forward in order to bring her to live with me in Germany and provide health assistance for her?

Comment: The citizenship of your mother is? As an EU Citizen, it would then only be a question of insuring that her financial needs are met (existing pension ; possible extra support from you) and if her present medical insurance in Portugal covers her in Germany.